# Como pegar o valor da session php e no campo select marcar como selected através de ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Oi, quem puder me ajudar seria ótimo. Já faz alguns dias que to quebrando a cabeça no código.

Tenho um form (que dá POST na própria página) com campos select de cidades e bairros. Quando seleciono a cidade, os bairros são listados conforme a cidade, através dos códigos mais abaixo.

Se o usuário seleciona a cidade e submete, atribui o valor para a `$_SESSION["cidade"]` daí o ajax vai lá e popula com os bairros da cidade.

Digamos que o usuário seleciona algum bairro e submete, atribui o valor para a `$_SESSION["bairro"]`.

Até aí, tudo bem! O usuário navega nos resultados, etc. quando ele volta para a página, gostaria que os campos estivessem populados conforme as sessões.

Não consigo, fazer isso no Ajax.
Quando o usuário volta no formulário, a cidade está lá mas o bairro não.

**Campos Selects**:

```
<select class="form-select text-muted mb-1" id="cidadeb" name="cidadeb">
<?php
    $resCidade = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT DISTINCT cidade FROM imoveis WHERE dataatualizacao >= 
    (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ".$diasatualizados." DAY) ORDER BY cidade ASC");
    while($rowCidade=$resCidade->fetch_array()) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$rowCidade['cidade'];?>" <?php if ($rowCidade['cidade'] == $cidade) echo "selected='selected'";?>><?=$rowCidade['cidade'];?></option>         
    <?} ?>
    <option value="0" <?php if ($cidade == "0") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Todas Cidades</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select text-muted mb-1" id="bairrob" name="bairrob">
    <option value="0" <?php if ($bairro == "0") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Todos Bairros</option>
</select>
```

Onde ...

```
$cidade = $_SESSION["cidade"];
$bairro = $_SESSION["bairro"];
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cidadeb').on('change rightnow', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lista_bairros.php',
        data: {'cidadeb': $('#cidadeb').val()},
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            if ($('#cidadeb').val() !== 'cidadeb') {
               $('#bairrob').html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
            }else{
               $('#bairrob').html('<option value="">Bairro</option>');
           }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if ($('#cidadeb').val() !== '') {
                $('#bairrob').html('<option value="">Selecione o Bairro</option>');
                $('#bairrob').append(data);
            }
        }
    });
  }).triggerHandler("rightnow");
});
</script>
```

**lista_bairros.php**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$postCidade = $_POST['cidadeb'];
$resBairro = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT bairro FROM imoveis WHERE cidade='".$postCidade."' GROUP BY bairro ORDER BY bairro ASC");
while($rowBairro=$resBairro->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowBairro['bairro'] ?>" <?php if ($rowBairro['bairro'] == '$bairro') echo "selected='selected'";?>><?php echo $rowBairro['bairro'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Cada vez que eu seleciono uma cidade, eu coloco valor na session, e coloco também para o bairro.

**Sessions:**

```
$_SESSION["cidade"] = "cidade que busquei";
$_SESSION["bairro"] = "bairro que busquei";
```

Não consigo fazer, é pegar o valor da `$_SESSION["bairro"]`, dar selected no select quando vem listado do ajax.

Acredito que seja nesta linha (no script), o ajuste:

```
$('#bairrob').html('<option value="">Selecione o Bairro</option>');
```

Seria grande ajuda, sem alguém aí pudesse me dar uma luz.
Estou aprendendo ainda.

Grato

Comment: Em que momento você define qual bairro deve aparecer?

Comment: Supondo que o usuário já escolheu o bairro, coloquei o valor na $_SESSION["bairro"]. Sempre que ele voltar no fomrulário, já dá selected naquele bairro. Via script que coloquei no post.

Comment: Vou reformular o raciocínio, em que momento no "código" é atribuído o valor da `$_SESSION["bairro"]`?

Comment: Quando da o POST no fomrulário. Ex: Selecionou a cidade, daí lista os bairros ... daí escolhe o bairro e submit. Neste momento atribui valor na session. `$_SESSION["bairro"] =$_POST["bairrob"];`

Comment: Então, mas esse trecho está no seu código? Coloca toda a parte relevante da operação no seu código

Comment: Certo, vou reformular melhor. Meu primeiro post. Desculpe. Gratidão pelo seu interesse em ajudar.

Comment: se já tem na session, não é mais fácil durante o `while` que gera os options verificar se tem o valor anteriormente selecionado na session e se tiver e for igual ao valor do option que está criando, também adicionar "selected" no option?

Comment: Fiz isso, mas não rolou. Pois quem manda é o script, ele é quem preenche. Tentei `<?php if ($rowBairro['bairro'] == '$bairro') echo "selected='selected'";?>` mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score -1):

vou tentar ajudar.

Acredito que sua maneira de pensar nesta situação que está atrapalhando. Se você já tem a cidade escolhida na sessão, não é necessário fazer 2 requisições (load e ajax). Pode já trazer os bairros no carregamento da tela.

Se permite vou fazer algumas alterações no código.

O ideal seria empacotar em funções ou classe mas vou seguir procedural como está fazendo.

```
<select class="form-select text-muted mb-1" id="cidadeb" name="cidadeb">
<?php
    $resCidade = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT DISTINCT cidade FROM imoveis WHERE dataatualizacao >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ".$diasatualizados." DAY) ORDER BY cidade ASC");
    while($rowCidade=$resCidade->fetch_array()) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$rowCidade['cidade'];?>" <?php if ($rowCidade['cidade'] == $cidade) echo "selected='selected'";?>><?=$rowCidade['cidade'];?></option>         
    <? } ?>
    <option value="0" <?php if ($cidade == "0") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Todas Cidades</option>
</select>

<select class="form-select text-muted mb-1" id="bairrob" name="bairrob">
    <option value="0" <?php if ($bairro == "0") echo "selected='selected'";?>>Todos Bairros</option>

<?php
    if( $cidade != "0" ){
        $resBairro = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT bairro FROM imoveis WHERE cidade='".$cidade."' GROUP BY bairro ORDER BY bairro ASC");

    while($rowBairro=$resBairro->fetch_array()) {
?>

<option <?php if ($bairro == $rowBairro['bairro']) echo "selected='selected'";?> value="<?php echo $rowBairro['bairro']; ?>"><?php echo $rowBairro['bairro'] ?></option>

<?php
    }
}
?>

</select>
```

Com este código você não precisa fazer o ajax apos o carregamento da página, você ja tem carregado os dados.

Informo que transitar o HTML do jeito que esta fazendo não é o ideal... vc pode usar JSON para trazer somente os dados e tratar o HTML no Js ...

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo! Testei lá, mas acredito, que o script ajax `$('#bairrob').html('<option value="">Selecione o Bairro</option>');` que esta escrevendo lá. Entendi a sua lógica.

Comment: Eu acho que vou ter que reformular minha pergunta, colocar mias informações. O usuário pode não querer bairro nenhum, mas sempre tem que popular a lista de bairros conforme a cidade.

Comment: Isso... coloque mais informações por favor... no caso que te coloquei só irá carregar os bairros caso tenha selecionado uma cidade... e só marca um bairro caso tenha o bairro selecionado, caso não tenha permanece o seu "Todos Bairros"

Comment: Entendi, mas como é o script ajax que popula bairro, toda vez que é carregada, ele coloca lá "Selecione o Bairro" , mesmo que a sua lógica esteja certíssima. Ele sobrepõe.

Comment: Remove o .triggerHandler("rightnow") e o rightnow do on("change rightnow") deixa só on("change")

Comment: Fiz isso, daí o usuário ao retornar a página, não popula os bairros. Precisa refazer a escolha de cidade, para ela popular bairros. Esse triger faz ela atualizar.

Comment: Coloca o codigo que escrevi pra vc e retira os trechos que falei... vai dar certo.

Comment: Deu certo Irmão! Tu é o cara! Farei mais uns testes para confirmar.

Comment: Então, sou tão novato no stackoverflow, que não consigo nem dar pontuação na tua resposta. Deu tudo certo! Tá funcionando o código. Gratidão irmão!